# oracle with php configuration

Tags: php, oracle, configuration

I am trying to connect to an oracle database with php. I've installed oci8 and edited my php.ini file to add:

```
extension_dir = "/opt/deploy/oracle/oci8-1.4.9/modules/"
extension=oci8.so
```

OCI8 doesn't show up any where in phpinfo() and when I do

```
if(!function_exists('oci_connect')) die('Oracle Not Installed');
```

It says Oracle is not installed.

Am I missing something? These directions were followed: 
http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.installation.php

Comment: @dearlbry yes, i did a apachect restart and a httpd -k restart

Comment: from the command line, what do you get when you run php -m ? And are you sure you got the right version of the instant client installed (32 vs 64 bit?)

Comment: @dearlbry PHP Warning:  Module 'oci8' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/deploy/oracle/oci8-1                                                                                                                                                    .4.9/modules/apc.so' - /opt/deploy/oracle/oci8-1.4.9/modules/apc.so: cannot open sha                                                                                                                                                    red object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line

Comment: @dearlbry If I comment out the extension_dir line, all I get is this: PHP Warning:  Module 'oci8' already loaded in Unknown on line 0

Comment: But does it show oci8 as one of the loaded modules in the list?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19438/discussion-between-dearlbry-and-milan)